# Create list from related tables in and set it as DataGrid in Devexpress WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid, code-first

I am using:

Entityramework 6 Code First 
Devexpress WPF

DBContext:

```
    public class Transport
    {
    [Key]
    public int TransportID {get; set;}
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    }

    public class Owner
    {
    [Key]
    public int OwnerID {get; set;}
    public int Name {get; set;}
    }

    public class TransportOwner
    {
    [Key]
    public int TransportOwnerID {get; set;}
    public int TransportID {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("TransportID")]
    public virtual Transport Transport { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OwnerID")]
    public virtual Owner Owner { get; set; }
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Transport> Transports { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<TransportOwner> TransportOwners { get; set; }
```

I created list:
List TransportOwnerList

What would be a final list witch I can pass to WPF?

```
var result = dbContext.TransportOwners.AsQueryable();
```

I also need to filter data first by TransportID witch value I get from another filtered lists selected item

```
result = result.Where(tr => tr.TransportID.Equals(SelectedItem.TransportID));
```

So how to format list from Transpot and Owners and set it as dataGrid itemSource?

I need such data:
TransportOwnerID, OwnerID, TransportID, ModelName, BrandName

```
TransportOwnerList = ... ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can project the needed fields:

```
var TransportOwnerList = result.Select(t => new 
                            {
                               t.TransportOwnerID,
                               t.OwnerID,
                               t.TransportID,
                               ModelName = t.Transport.Model,
                               BrandName = t.Transport.Brand,
                               ... // other fields
                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: And how to pass it to WPF form? I need to create new list, type <TransportOwner> ?

Comment: In MVC we create a ViewModel that is passed to the form (view). Looks like WPF has something similar.http://www.markwithall.com/programming/2013/03/01/worlds-simplest-csharp-wpf-mvvm-example.html

Comment: Yes it has :) We use ViewModel also

Comment: Yes it has :) We use ViewModel also... but I am not lucky to construct list from two entities... actually don't know how to describe list... I have List<Transport>, List<OwnerTransport> and need new one List<OwnerTransportTransport> data from List1 and List2. So TransportOwnerList above results right data... and is the last thing I don't know how to write correctly List<OwnerTransporTransport> = TransportOwnerList :)